# How to reach maximum of product

Tags: sql-server, sum, max

I am new to sql and I am attempting to write a query that takes a maximum after two separate columns are multiplied together.

One table is called portfolio and contains the amount of shares purchased. The other table is called investment and has the price paid. I am just trying to get the highest (max) purchase price after multiplying the two values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your table definition

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean but my tables are set up as follows:    portfolio: port_id, buy_sell, amount and investment is inv_id, port_id, quantity

Comment: @@Kevin, it's to difficult to answer without `input` argument (table design - column and their types) and `output` argument (what are you going to achieve and how it should looks like) - it would be brilliant if you link us to your http://sqlfiddle.com/ example

Comment: I don't see field price in a table investment.And do you what to use  max function per port_id?

Comment: Do you literally just want the maximum figure - without any other info like *which* investment(s) produced the max value? Do you want all max valets in case of a tie?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all you want is the overall max, and that the price paid stored in the investment table is the 'quantity' column and the number of shares purchased is the 'amount' column on the portfolio table, AND that the link between the portfolio and investment tables is the 'port_id' you want something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(t2.amount * t1.quantity) AS 'Max Purchase Price'
FROM Investment t1
    JOIN Portfolio t2 ON t1.port_id = t2.port_id
```

If you need more columns you can add them to the SELECT list and you'll need to add in a  GROUP BY (plenty of posts on SO related to this).  Hope this helps!